# Get query result column value of tinyint as true/false in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I have column in `my_table` which has datatype of tinyint 
 [image: a column of table contains tinyint datatype]

CodeIgniter model class:

```
public function get_all() {
    $query = $this->db->get('my_table');
    return $query->result();
}
```

query result return the value of is_active field as a string "0" / "1". I want it as true/false. So that, json data of that field is true/false. 
Controller class:

```
$query_result = $this->model->get_all();
echo json_encode($query_result);
```

How I get this?

**UPDATE:**
query result array is:

```
Array (
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [brand_id] => 1014
        [brand_name] => Coca Cola
        [brand_logo] => coca_cola_logo2.png
        [is_active] => 1
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [brand_id] => 1015
        [brand_name] => Hallmark
        [brand_logo] => hallmark_logo.jpg
        [is_active] => 0
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [brand_id] => 1016
        [brand_name] => Binjar
        [brand_logo] => binjar3.png
        [is_active] => 1
    )

)
```

Comment: `array_map(function($value) { return ($value?'true':'false');}, $query_result);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the conversion is not needed.

But if you insist...

On the PHP side, in addition to using `array_map()` you can walk through the result set and cast the values to boolean.

```
foreach($query_result as $result){
  $result->is_active = (bool) $result->is_active;
}
```

Simple as that... but pointless. The integers 1 & 0 will evaluate as TRUE and FALSE using loose comparisons eg.

```
var_dump(1 == TRUE);
var_dump(0 == TRUE);
```

will output

> boolean true
>
> boolean false

Javascript is also able to test the "truthfulness" of the returned data whether the value returned is `true`, `"1"`, or the integer `1`.

Here is a controller and view to test the premise.

**Controller:**

```
<?php

class Testcase extends CI_Controller
{
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('form');
  }

  function index()
  {
    $this->load->view('test_view');
  }

  public function respond()
  {
    $data = array('asString' => '1', 'asBool' => TRUE, 'asInt' => 1);
    echo json_encode($data);
  }

}
```

**View:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?= form_open("#", ['id' => 'form']); ?>
    <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Click Me!">
    <?= form_close(); ?>
    <div id="as-string"></div>
    <div id="as-bool"></div>
    <div id="as-int"></div>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#form").submit(function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'testcase/respond',
            data: $('#form').serializeArray(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
              console.log(data);
              if (data.asString == true) {
                $('#as-string').text('String returned is True');
              } else {
                $('#as-string').text('String returned is False');
              }
              if (data.asBool == true) {
                $('#as-bool').text('Boolean returned is True');
              } else {
                $('#as-bool').text('Boolean returned is False');
              }
              if (data.asInt == true) {
                $('#as-int').text('Integer returned is True');
              } else {
                $('#as-int').text('Integer returned is False');
              }
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Submitting the form produces this result in the browser

> String returned is True
>
> Boolean returned is True
>
> Integer returned is True

Change the return to the various representations of FALSE like so,

```
$data = array('asString' => '0', 'asBool' => FALSE, 'asInt' => 0);
echo json_encode($data);
```

And clicking the button produces

> String returned is False
>
> Boolean returned is False
>
> Integer returned is False

Notice that the javascript is using loose equality (`==`) for the condition check. If you change to strict equality (`===`) the results change.

Changing the success function to use strict equality...

```
success: function (data) {
  console.log(data);
  if (data.asString === true) {
    $('#as-string').text('String returned is True');
  } else {
    $('#as-string').text('String returned is False');
  }
  if (data.asBool === true) {
    $('#as-bool').text('Boolean returned is True');
  } else {
    $('#as-bool').text('Boolean returned is False');
  }
  if (data.asInt === true) {
    $('#as-int').text('Integer returned is True');
  } else {
    $('#as-int').text('Integer returned is False');
  }
}
```

and returning this data from the controller

```
$data = array('asString' => '1', 'asBool' => TRUE, 'asInt' => 1);
```

produces this result

> String returned is False
>
> Boolean returned is True
>
> Integer returned is False

With "false" data...

```
$data = array('asString' => '0', 'asBool' => FALSE, 'asInt' => 0);
```

the results are this

> String returned is False
>
> Boolean returned is False
>
> Integer returned is False

So, by using loose equality (`==`) you can make a conditional test without fussing about the data type that your controller is returning.

Comment: conversion from integer to boolean is happened in javascript. But i want it in controller (php) class. So that, `is_active` always set to as true/false.

Comment: But you stated "I want it as true/false. So that, json data of that field is true/false." and json data points to javascript not PHP. There is no point in making the conversion for either PHP or javascript. Using PHP `(0 == FALSE)` will evaluate to FALSE and `(1==TRUE)`  will evaluate to TRUE every time.

Comment: Sorry for misleading you. In some case, i don't need javascript as i can do `json_decode()` in php. i don't want to convert it after decoding/parsing. I want it before encoding. Is it possible?

Comment: Again. The conversion is a pointless waste of processing as the integers 1 and 0 can be evaluated as boolean without any extra effort. But I will add another solution to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function to change the 0/1 to true/false:

```
$query_result = $this->model->get_all();
$returnArr = array_map(function($value) { return ($value?'true':'false');}, $query_result);
echo json_encode($returnArr);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/578820)

---

**Update 1:** Retain other values

Change your `array_map` to:

```
array_map(function($value) { 
    if($value === 1) {
        return 'true';
    }
    else if($value === 0){
        return 'false';
    }
    else{
        return $value;
    }
}, $query_result);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/578829)

Comment: I have multiple columns in query result. this snippet delete other column, but i need all those

Comment: @ARiF Updated! check out

Comment: Does not work. Still it is 0/1. Though, first solution works but delete other columns.

Comment: @Thamilan I have updated my question, where you can see the array of the query result.